# WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function format_example at ...> and will run it as-is

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question is related to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36921) and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35101) one here. I am using PyCharm on Windows and Python 3.7.8 and Tensorflow 2.2.0:

```
print (sys.version)
3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

print(tf.__version__)
2.2.0
```

When I run this code from this [colab](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub) tutorial:

```
import os

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)
IMG_SIZE = 160 # All images will be resized to 160x160

def format_example(image, label):
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  image = (image/127.5) - 1
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return image, label
```

and then try to run this line:

```
train = raw_train.map(format_example)
```

I get the WARNING:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function format_example at 0x00000265A2DB4E58> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: Unable to locate the source code of <function format_example at 0x00000265A2DB4E58>. Note that functions defined in certain environments, like the interactive Python shell do not expose their source code. If that is the case, you should to define them in a .py source file. If you are certain the code is graph-compatible, wrap the call using @tf.autograph.do_not_convert. Original error: could not get source code
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
```

I only get this WARNING when using PyCharm on my local pc. When I run it in colab no problems. What is the issue here and is this relevant or can I ignore the WARNING?

Comment: Could you check in colab: "Runtime > View runtime logs" and see, if the Warning is there? Colab sometimes hides warnings and I have a hunch, that it will be there. Nonetheless, the issue is that Autograph cannot optimize the "format_example" function. With not so computation heavy functions this doesn't mean anything, as performance gain is minimal.

Comment: @AndreaAngeli Thanks for the comment, I checked colab, no, this warning is not there.

Comment: I confirm that I am seeing this warning in my local JupyterLab and not in Colab.

Answer (score 1):

Like OP I get this warning in JupyterLab but not in Colab. But this only happens if I use a lambda.

```py
train = raw_train.map(lambda x: x)
```

If I use a named function like the OP is doing here the warning goes away.

```py
train = raw_train.map(format_example)
```

`DataSet.map()` always builds a graph even if you are in the eager mode. I think the graph builder is running into some kind of confusion.

Comment: I used a name function and the error didn't go away, the best option for now is get rid of the message using `tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert` as suggested by @DevLoverUmar.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the warning message, you can decorate the `format_example` function as

```
train = raw_train.map(tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert(format_example))
```

Or

```
train = raw_train.map(tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert(lambda x: x*2))
```

Comment: This answer does not explain the problem.